# I get an error when creating Apk: JAVA_HOME

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, build, apk, java-home

I have download and installed Java, but having `JAVA_HOME` invalid error.

How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an environment variable called `JAVA_HOME` that points to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151`.

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151` does not exist on your computer.

You need to make sure you have Java installed first, and then edit your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to the proper location.

Here's a decent 'how to' for changing environment variables in Windows: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: error screen http://prntscr.com/hia2n0
system veriable = http://prntscr.com/hia30j // path = http://prntscr.com/hia3b1
java folder = http://prntscr.com/hia3oi

If I do everything, I get an error I could not solve it somehow